# Android Contacts Can't retrieve data

Tags: android, cursor, contacts

Android Contacts is driving me mad! 
This code is returning empty cursors, but the contacts exists! Can anyone see what I can't?

```
        ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        String query = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = " +pickedID;
        Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,query , null, null);
        pCur.moveToFirst();
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                    contactPhone.setText(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA)));
                } 
                pCur.close();

               query = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID +" = " +pickedID;
                pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI, null,query , null, null);
                pCur.moveToFirst();
                        while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                            contactPhone.setText(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));
                        } 
                        pCur.close();
```

Comment: Please have a look of google contact loader example https://github.com/codepath/android-contacts-loader-demo

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with the null cursor and my problem was that, I had forgotten to add
the following line of code in the `Manifest.xml` file:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the entire cause of the problem, but you are calling

```
pCur.moveToFirst();
```

which moves the cursor to the first entry.  Then you immediately call

```
while (pCur.moveToNext())
```

which moves the cursor to the second entry.  So you are skipping the first entry.

Leave out the `pCur.moveToFirst();` and just leave the while loop and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the root of your problem is how you initially retrieve the contact list.

```
 Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,query , null, null);
```

should be..

```
Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, null);
```

Comment: but I'm querying a phone number based on a contact ID from a previous query. Just tried this    String query = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID +" = " +pickedID;
   Cursor pCur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,query , null, null);

   pCur.moveToFirst();
           while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
             contactPhone.setText(pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DATA)));
            } 
            pCur.close();       but its still returning an empty cursor